# MySQL event scheduler -- Event running at wrong time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, timezone, event, mysql-event

I have created a event to run EVERY 1 DAY at 3:15 (am). I know that timezones affects events and actually I create a query to check the START time in mysql.event (GMT timezone) and information_schema.event (Local system timezone/EST for this example).

As you can see in the image below, my event is supposed to run every day at 7:15 GMT or 3:15 EST but following the two last columns %*lastExecuted*% you can see tha actually it ran 4 hours and 15 minutes later than expected.

[image: Event details]

This is the creation code:

```
CREATE DEFINER="vpladmin"@"%" EVENT "call_biz_review_lookups" ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-05-03 03:15:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN

INSERT INTO.....

END
```

sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'

Comment: The server was not down any of that time?

Comment: There's no wierdness with [timezones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html) that are 30 mins off UTC? Do you have work outsourced to India for example?

Comment: @RickJames I confirmed that the server was up all the time. Thanks.

Comment: @Vérace I know that. But for this case is different. Check the query in the attached image on my post. Thanks

Comment: That's off by 15 minutes; can't point at India.

Comment: @RickJames just grasping at straws! Maybe a slippage of lakh seconds? :-)

Comment: @Vérace maybe a fortnight/crore.  Or a pileup of leap-seconds.

Comment: @JesusUzcanga - Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`.  How is the server (the OS) configured?